# Import Error: Cannot import name '_path' PYTHON

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror, spyder

I know other people went through this kind of problem but I still can't fix the problem. I just began to programming.

I use spyder IDE and get the following error when I run the code.

```
File "C:\Users\kaany\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _path, rcParams

ImportError: cannot import name '_path'
```

When I remove 'import matplotlib as plt' from my code everything goes fine.

I have numpy 1.13.3 and matplotlib 2.1.0

I'd appreciate if someone provided any solution to this.

Comment: This error occurs if you have a wrong version of matplotlib installed or if your matplotlib version does not match the numpy version in use.

Comment: I have numpy 1.13.3 and matplotlib 2.1.0

Comment: What I mean is that the binaries are probably incompatible. This could e.g. happen if you installed a version for 32bit on a 64bit python or vice versa. There is no such information given in the question, hence it is pretty much impossible to say more at this point.